# Memory occupied by a quite large array MySQL result set in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, memcached

Let the following table with about ~100 000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_code` (
  `value` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I need to query this table very often, so I was thinking to put the result set (as array) in Redis or Memcached.

I did some math (<s>utf-8 is 4 bytes</s> not true, see @Daan comment, 4 bytes could be still a pessimistic guess):

- `value`: (1 * 4) + (64 * 4) = 388 bytes
- `type`: (1 * 4) + (16 * 4) = 68 bytes
- `product_id`: (1 * 4) + (32* 4) = 132 bytes

One row = 588 bytes at max, total should be 58800000 bytes = **~56MB** + indexes size. Is this correct?

But it seems too much to me, in fact right now I have ~50 000 rows in that table and the following query shows 6864896 bytes = **~6.5 MB**:

```
SELECT 
    DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH AS size
FROM
    information_schema.TABLES
where
    TABLE_NAME = 'product_code'
```

Comment: `UTF-8` is multibyte character encoding. Characters can have 1 to 6 bytes, not just 4.

Comment: you got let's say 100.000 records, how many of them do you need each time? how much time does require the query? is it better to store (with memcache or similar) the resultset? how do you update this cache?

Comment: And why is `product_id` a `varchar(32)` shouldn't that be an integer?

Comment: @Daan because it's not integer :)

Comment: @Goikiu how or when to update the cache is not by biggest concern. Codes are used mainly to show search suggestions and when performing the actual search (code search).

Comment: @Daan It can happen that some client do want human code, a better solution is to have a field for an auto-generated id too

Comment: Well and what is your problem? Slow query on table? If yes, show us slow query...

Comment: Why there's a need to place all the results in an array or stored in Redis/Memcache? Aren't the queries specific to a single or a number of product_id but not necessarily 100k of product_id at once?

Comment: @venca question is about memory occupied and why my math differs from the actual table size.

Comment: You wrote *I need to query this table very often, so I was thinking to put the result set (as array) in Redis or Memcached.* So I ask why you want to put it in Redis? Why? What problem solves if you put table in Redis?

Comment: Caching MySQL results in any other system will only be slower. Much slower. MySQL's InnoDB is one of the best in-memory managers, and MySQL caches its data. If you try to optimize it, you'll just waste RAM and hinder performance. Solution to your problem is to ditch your optimization and increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting in MySQL. Then all you have to do is keep querying MySQL. It will always be faster than Redis or Memcached, they can't measure up to speed of InnoDB.

Comment: @Mjh actually a lot of PHP libraries (like Doctrine) use **result set cache** in order to not touching the disk (with memcached/redis and other backends). Are they all wrong?

Comment: Your columns are varchar so they should take only the space they need, in your case the value column varchar(64) it can take between 1 and 64 - so you are actually calculating the maximum size

Comment: @gremo - I never mentioned anything about disk. What I said is that InnoDB keeps its working data set in memory. If it already keeps it there, why would you cache it somewhere else? How is that faster? Have you seen any tests of InnoDB versus other in-memory solutions? Do you know how php handles mysql connections internally? I won't comment on Doctrine because I am not familiar with it so it would be unfair for me to comment anything, but I never assume that if a library exists for a long time that they are correct in all of their decisions.

Comment: @Mjh I don't know about MySQL internals and in fact I didn't say anything about memcached being faster than MySQL internal pool/buffers/memory.  I'm just worried about memory size vs query performance. You said _Caching MySQL results in any other system will only be slower_  so I put Doctrine (and other libraries that use caching) in the middle and I like to know what do you thing about this trategy (just to learn more). Thank you.

Comment: So let's start from the scratch - MySQL is already built with performance / caching in mind. InnoDB allows you to tune it, so huge databases use tons of ram and they control how much is allocated to InnoDB via `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable. InnoDB will cache its working data there. As for *how much* it will use - I don't think it uses optimum sizes really. But the fact is, if you have sufficient ram, if you queried your table and if it fits the ram - it will be there. There is no need to additionally cache it.

Comment: @Mjh I see. Is there any way to see what's being cached?

Comment: Not really. There's explanation on [MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_buffer_pool) and a few thoughts from DBA's at [this link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56494/making-sense-of-innodb-buffer-pool-stats). If you are concerned about the sizes, I would suggest taking a look at [TokuDB](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.6/tokudb/tokudb_installation.html) which is InnoDB drop-in replacement, but it boasts compression rate of about 11x of InnoDB while maintaining the same or better performance (ACID compliant as well).